# Random six letter string in Python

Tags: python, random, types

Ok, let me rephrase my whole problem. I want to be able to write a Python script that lets me type random letters into Microsoft Word without my keyboard. So for example, I can generate a random string of letters with a code such as the following:

```
import string, random
a = string.ascii_uppercase
b = random.choice(a)
c = random.choice(a)
d = random.choice(a)
print a + b + c
```

Let's say the code prints out 'HVF'. I want to type this string into Microsoft Word with the same script, which is easy using ctypes. However, that program is only capable of typing only that string 'HVF'. I want a program that will generate any random string of letters, then type that string into Microsoft Word.

Comment: Keypress functions only work if the program you are trying to push key presses into has the focus, or the keypress algorithm has a window handle to target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your edited question, looks like you're having trouble looping your program. This is absolute beginner material, so you're clearly jumping light years ahead by diving into `ctypes` to produce a keystroke. Ah well, here we go anyway....

```
import random, string

NUM_CHARS = 6 # how long the string should be
textbank = string.ascii_uppercase * NUM_CHARS

while True:
    word = random.sample(textbank,NUM_CHARS)
    for letter in word:
        press_key_however_you_do_it(letter)
        # I have no idea how you're implementing this, but you do
    press_key_however_you_do_it(" ")
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessarily the best way depending what you're doing (for performance reasons), but you could use `random.sample` instead of using `random.choice` one at a time and just join the results.

```
>>> import random, string
>>> ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, 6))
'SWUHCK'
>>> ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, 6))
'WUYOMS'
>>> ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, 6))
'PMAHEL'
```

A couple of people have noted in the comments that this is **sampling without replacement**. That means there is no possibility of duplicate letters.

If you want that, you can use something like @acushner suggested:

```
>>> ''.join(string.ascii_uppercase[random.randint(0, 25)] for i in xrange(6))
```

Or the possibly faster solution suggested by @adsmith:

```
>>> ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase * 6, 6))
```

Which samples without replacement from a long string containing exactly six duplicates of each letter. :)

Comment: I don't think you understand. I want Python to _type_ it, into Microsoft Word for instance

Comment: You're right, I don't. The title of your question is "Random six-letter string in Python" and you say that the problem is needing to "type it into Microsoft Word" but that some other thread "allowed you to do the typing part of it." If you're having trouble with that part, then post a question about _just that_. What have you tried? What is not working?

Comment: `random.sample` won't give words with duplicate letters, though.

Comment: I added the code in my question to the end of the program in the link. That was what I tried. I want to _type_ into Microsoft Word a _random_ six letter string. Is that so hard to comprehend?

Comment: @eddybob123 only in that you give no indication what is failing. Two-Bit gave you perfectly good code to create 6-letter strings. Since you haven't included your implementation of `PressKey` and `ReleaseKey`, we're assuming those work as intended, and if they don't, SO can't help you fix it since we don't know how it works. Clean up your question if your answers aren't up to snuff.

Comment: @eddybob123 You _type_ at a keyboard. You want to _send artificial keystrokes_ to an arbitrary process, while not specifying what libraries, OS, or Python version you are using, and none of this has anything to do with the question you asked. And you're not going to get very much help by smarting off at people volunteering to help you write code.

Comment: just a note that this is sampling without replacement. it might be better to just do something like `''.join(string.ascii_uppercase[random.randint(0, 25)] for i in xrange(6))`

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist It's probably faster to just do `textbank = string.ascii_uppercase * 6` and `random.sample` from that instead. It still lowers your chance of duplicate letters, but not considerably. Note that it's certainly slower to build the list each time -- build it once and point `random.sample` at it!